# My CodeIgniter project not running on WAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I have my project developed in CodeIgniter which works perfect on XAMPP Server but Not working on WAMP server.

I've changed

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = '';
```

and .htaccess I've

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Homepage of website appears properly. But no link is working whenever I click on any link wamp server homepage appears in French version.

Project run properly on WAMP only if there is index.php in URL.

e.g.

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/welcome/view (This link doesn't work)
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/view (Links works properly)
```

Comment: Correction in Question:
But no link is working whenever I click on any link wamp server homepage appears without wamp server logo on it.

Comment: Maybe you could flag to correct answer, seems polite...

Answer (score 5):

Try this one, it's working everywhere :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Enable the mod_rewrite in your `httpd.conf` file

In my case I have installed WAMP on local disk C

to find httpd file just navigate to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.6\conf`

open httpd.conf file with notepad editor then find the line below:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and uncomment it

save the file and restart Apache for the new setting to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

check `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` file.
it would be like below

```
RewriteBase /your project folder name/
```

copy below code and paste it in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter/



#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?/#$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php;
```

hope it will help you. and check one thing i.e your url. if there is any ~ symbol then `.htaccess` file will be different. otherwise the above code will work. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I did mention that in question, I already have RewriteBase.
RewriteBase /codeigniter/

Really freaking me out.

Comment: please say me your folder structure starting from  "www" folder

Comment: I remove ErrorDocument 404 /index.php line from .htaccess now it says "The requested URL /codeigniter/welcome/view was not found on this server."

/codeigniter/index.php/welcome/view is working okay

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine On    //missed this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: what `routes` do you have in your $routes.php?

Comment: you seems to be a lot of experience on CodeIgniter. Any advice for me. Should I try for solution or Just Install XAMPP

Comment: sorry but m not that experienced but I had the same prob as yours and got fixed by adding the above content in my .htaccess, so thought it might help you too, aneways gudluck